# How to wait for the children processes to send signals?

Tags: c, signals, fork

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

void handler(int signumber)
{
    return;
}

int main()
{
    int i, pid;
    int children_count = 5;
    int arr_childprocesses[5];
    int parent_pid = getpid();

    for(i=0;i<children_count;i++)
    {
        pid = fork();
        if(pid == -1) 
        {
            perror("Err");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if(pid == 0) break;

        arr_childprocesses[i] = pid;
    }

    if (pid == 0) // children
    {
        kill(parent_pid,SIGUSR1);
        printf("Child(%d) sig sent. Waiting 5s...\n",getpid());
        sleep(5);
        printf("Child(%d) terminated.\n",getpid());
    }
    else // parent
    {
        signal(SIGUSR1,handler);
        for(i=0;i<children_count;++i)
        {
            waitpid(arr_childprocesses[i],NULL,0);
            printf("Parent: Signal received.\n");
        }
        printf("Parent(%d) signals received. Waiting 3s...\n",getpid());
        sleep(3);
        printf("Parent(%d) terminated.\n",getpid());
    }

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); 
}
```

I want to wait until all the children send me a signal. Then do some work with the children and with the parent too. But the program stops until all the children terminate. How should I do this?

Result:

[image]

Update 1: full code plus result included

Comment: `waitpid()` does not wait on a signal from the child but on child's state change, that is end, stop or (re-)start. Those changes of state go along with a signal however.

Comment: Ah, you are right. I think i should use different logic, like increasing a global int counter in the signal handler. and use something like this instead of the waitpid():

while(counter<5) ;

Answer (score 3):

You are probably facing a race here.

The parent receives the `SIGUSR1` before its handler for this signal had been set up. As the default behaviour on receiving a `SIGUSR1` is to end, the parent dies.

You want to setup the signal handler inside the parent **before** forking off the child.

(If from the programs design it is unacceptbale for the child to have `SIGUSR1` signal handler set up, just call `signal(SIGUSR1, SIG_DFL)` as the 1st statement inside the child to deinstall this handler.)

To prove this theory you might like to **temporarily** add a `sleep(1);` inside the child just before the call to `kill()`.

---

As a hint to fulfill your assignment:

Have a look at [`sigaction()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) as it provides a much more powerful interface to signalling then the function `signal()` does. Especially read about the `SA_SIGINFO` flag as it enables passing a `siginfo_t` typed variable to your signal handler. This latter variable carries info on who (identified by PID) sent the signal, which is the key to your solution.

Comment: thanks your answer, but it didn't helped. I included my full example with a result too. could you check it?

Comment: @BlackCat: Ok, but the race is still around.